# Bash script in ANT to remove text in file

Tags: bash, sed

I have this script:

```
# run this command to create production version of project.html
/<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTION|END PRODUCTION -->/  { next }
/<!-- (BEGIN|END) DEVELOPMENT -->/ { skip = !skip; next }
!skip
```

Long story short, it replaces text in an HTML file when I compile my application for production. It removes all code between my `BEGIN DEVELOPMENT` comment and `END DEVELOPMENT` comment and uncomments the `BEGIN PRODUCTION` code. Here's an example of the text that would be replaced:

```
<!-- BEGIN DEVELOPMENT -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
<!-- END DEVELOPMENT -->

<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTION
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.min.js"></script>
END PRODUCTION -->
```

This is working great. But I need to do the same in a PHP file and I need to use this syntax instead:

```
/* BEGIN DEVELOPMENT */
{PHP CODE}
/* END DEVELOPMENT */
/* BEGIN PRODUCTION
{PHP CODE}
END PRODUCTION */
```

It follows the same concept but I can't get the shell script working. Can somebody tell me why this is not correct?:

```
# run this command to create production version of project.html
/\/* BEGIN PRODUCTION|END PRODUCTION *\//  { next }
/\/* (BEGIN|END) DEVELOPMENT *\// { skip = !skip; next }
!skip
```

Thanks for any help!

As per the comment below, here's the correct syntax and it works:

```
# run this command to create production version of project.html
/\/\* BEGIN PRODUCTION|END PRODUCTION \*\//  { next }
/\/\* (BEGIN|END) DEVELOPMENT \*\// { skip = !skip; next }
!skip
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be escaping the `*` too?

Comment: Woah - I completely missed that. Checking now to see if that solves my issue

Comment: @Jaypal - This solves part of the problem but it's not removing the "END PRODUCTION */" trailing comment. Any ideas?

Comment: Scratch that - everything works! thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This can now be marked as answered:

```
# run this command to create production version of project.html
/\/\* BEGIN PRODUCTION|END PRODUCTION \*\//  { next }
/\/\* (BEGIN|END) DEVELOPMENT \*\// { skip = !skip; next }
!skip
```